# Using apache mod_wsgi test error ---windows environment

Tags: apache, flask, mod-wsgi

I have seen many solutions similar to my problem, but there is no one that suits me. Please help me solve it.
First, I want to test my apache's mod_wsgi.

httd.conf:

```
LoadFile "e:/zt_6.27/python/python35.dll"
LoadModule wsgi_module "e:/zt_6.27/python/lib/site- 
packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp35-win_amd64.pyd"
WSGIPythonHome "e:/zt_6.27/python"

<VirtualHost *:80>       
    WSGIScriptAlias /myapp E:\zt_6.27\Apache24\htdocs\myapp.wsgi
    <Directory 'E:\zt_6.27\Apache24\htdocs'>
        Require all granted
        Require host ip
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

myapp.wsgi:

```
def application(environ,start_response):
  status='200 OK'
  output='Hello wsgi!'
  response_headers=[('Content-type','text/plain'),('Content-Length',str(len(output)))]
  start_response(status,response_headers)
  return[output]
```

I restart my apache service,call "http://localhost/myapp".

It return 500 Internal Server Error.

I open the error.log of apache.

it show:

```
[Fri Aug 10 10:33:35.803119 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 9252:tid 1408] [client 
::1:57261] mod_wsgi (pid=9252): Exception occurred processing WSGI script 
'E:/zt_6.27/Apache24/htdocs/myapp.wsgi'.
[Fri Aug 10 10:33:35.803119 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 9252:tid 1408] [client 
::1:57261] TypeError: sequence of byte string values expected, value of type 
str found\r
```

I checked the code carefully and it is no problem.

What did I do wrong?

Other than this,I successfully ran this code yesterday, it went wrong today.

help me please!!

Answer (score 0):

If using Python 3, you must use:

```
def application(environ,start_response):
  status = '200 OK'
  output = b'Hello wsgi!'
  response_headers = [('Content-type','text/plain'),('Content-Length',str(len(output)))]
  start_response(status,response_headers)
  return[output]
```

That is, change to:

```
output = b'Hello wsgi!'
```

The list returned, must have byte strings in it, not unicode strings.

To return unicode strings you would need to convert them to byte strings. I cheated here by just marking it as byte string to start with, but you should encode them to byte strings as UTF-8 instead.

I would suggest using a micro framework like Flask as it will handle these sorts of details for you.

Comment: But another problem has arisen, when  I run with flask.It return error"[Fri Aug 10 12:19:19.108314 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8688:tid 1408] [client ::1:65087] ImportError: No module named 'flask'\r"

Comment: how can I fix this mistake?

Comment: If the answer above fixed your original question, accept it, and create a new question for your next problem. The obvious answer to your new problem is, have you installed Flask.